# Is there a way/library to store files in the app's iCloud Container in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs, icloud-documents

Looking for a way to store files (a realm database) to iCloud for backup purposes.
The user can create and restore those backups.

I have tried using RNFS (react-native-fs).
But got stuck when looking for a way to read the location of the iCloud Contianer. I thik RNFS is not able to get the URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier on it's own.

Ultimately I would like to let the user backup the full realm database to iCLoud (and if possible Google Drive) and to restore the backup in case of a device change.

I know Realm has sync functionality but for now I would like to offer users a free solution for backing up their data.

Comment: Been trying to figure this one out myself for a similar use case. Wondering as it's been a while was anything found?